# show all errors except notice and strict in php

Tags: php, error-handling, error-log

i want to log all php errors except notice and strict
i tried the following code

```
error_reporting(E_ALL &^ E_NOTICE &^ E_STRICT);
```

but it gave me an error "unexpected ^"

Answer (score 8):

You need to use [`& ~`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php#refsect1-function.error-reporting-examples) instead of `&^`:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT);
```

Comment: what is the differenc between ^ and &~
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE );
error_reporting(E_ALL &~ E_NOTICE );

Comment: `^` and `~` is a bitwise operators, `~` means not , so `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE` means E_ALL and not E_NOTICE, while `^` means XOR, `E_STRICT ^ E_NOTICE` means don't print E_STRICT and E_NOTICE

Answer (score 2):

Please try this `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT);` `~` use this sign for except
http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php